# Performance issue with big React state object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a function `updateRowValue`, which updates a value in a row in a table based on user input. There are 11 columns whose values can be updated by the user, and the user can add/remove rows. I am currently testing on a table with 7 rows, and there is a severe lag between pressing a key on the keyboard and the change appearing on the screen.

Each time the user presses a key on their keyboard, the state is updated (I am using a controlled MUI TextField). I don't think the amount of inputs is the actual problem (though I might be wrong). I think the problem is that I have to traverse through the `table_rows` object every time a value should be updated.

My question is basically: Can I update the value each time the user presses a key on their keyboard and also make the app feel responsive to the key presses? If so, then how?

```
function updateRowValue(row_id, attribute, new_value){
    const new_row = Object.assign(table_rows[row_id], {[attribute]: new_value});
    const newState = Object.assign(table_rows, { [row_id]: {...table_rows[row_id], ...new_row} });

    setTableRows({...table_rows, ...newState});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative to the whole mess I had created. Instead of trying to optimize how I save the states (which might not even be possible) I realized that I don't actually *need* the states. I can access the form values directly.

By adding `inputProps={{"data-row": row_id, "data-cell": cell_id}}` to the TextField, and then using `document.querySelectorAll("[data-row]")`, it is easy and fast to access all cells and their data when it is actually relevant to use them (saving them to the database in my case).